# Can I find the original name of a field in information schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

I'm trying to perform a source to target mapping which essentially maps the original field name to the rename in a view.

Is there a way to do this using information schema? I'm using a postgres database

I do have access to the code, but there are too much interference to use regex to split out what I need.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `pg_depend` contains what you need: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-depend.html

Comment: I was thinking something along the line of column_domain_usage, but in Information Schema on the system, this particular table is empty. What I am wanting is the Source Column name as well as the ALIAS.